# jquery .html throws error when input a php variable with html tags

Tags: jquery

I want to display the content of a php variable that has html tags, in a div with jquery, but it trows me an error unexpected token

```
jQuery(".button").click(function(){

    jQuery("#single-post-container").html("<?php echo $content;?>");

});
```

the variable $content has html tags that I need, this is the exact string

```
<h2>TEST</h2>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod 
 tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim 
 veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea 
 commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate 
 velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat 
 cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id 
 est laborum.</p>
```

the content variable is the result of a wordpress function, so I cannot add quotes manually to escape the tags.

what can I do?

Comment: you'll need at least some quotes around that html string (for javascript): `html('<?php echo $content;?>')`. But then you might need to [escape quotes](http://php.net/manual/en/function.addslashes.php) in php, depending on what that `$content` looks like.

Comment: I suppose this missing `"` is just a typo here: `jQuery(".button)`

Comment: Please show the content of `$content`.

Comment: _"something like this"_ doesn't help. Does it contain quotes? Then you need to escape them. If it doesn't contain quotes, then the updated code should run.

Comment: doesnt contain quotes, just html tags and words, the code above doesnt work

Comment: please show the rendered html/js of this part (_after_ php)! Should be something like `....html("<h2>Title.....</p>");`

Comment: thanks jeff for your patience, I just put the exact text in the post

Comment: javascript doesn't like the newlines in the string. So either remove them in php or [change them](http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php) to `<br>`.

Comment: see this working fiddle _without_ newlines: http://jsfiddle.net/qgjf1om0/

Comment: _OR_ change the quotes around that html string to `\``. See another fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qgjf1om0/1/ Further reading: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/805107/creating-multiline-strings-in-javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is, that your rendered html from php contains newline characters. The rendered html/js will look like this:

```
jQuery(".button").click(function(){

    jQuery("#single-post-container").html("<h2>TEST</h2>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod 
 tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim 
 veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea 
 commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate 
 velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat 
 cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id 
 est laborum.</p>");

});
```

Javascript doesn't like multiline strings - *unless* you wrap them in backticks ` instead of single ' or double " quotes:

```
jQuery(".button").click(function(){

    jQuery("#single-post-container").html(`<h2>TEST</h2>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod 
 tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim 
 veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea 
 commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate 
 velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat 
 cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id 
 est laborum.</p>`);

});
```

You can test on this working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qgjf1om0/1/

Further reading: 
[Template Literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)